# System.Format Exception

Tags: c#, string, exception

The programm i wrote throws up an Exception because of this code:

```
queryString = String.Format("INSERT INTO Playlists (PlaylistID, PlaylistName, PlaylistCreator) VALUES ('{0}', '{1]', '{2}');", CurrentPlaylistID, playlistInfo[1], playlistInfo[0]);
```

All Variables are Strings. I also have a similiar String.Format after this an it works fine. There are also 3 Variables, all are Strings.

Can't find a way to solve this Error, it says formatting Error, but why?

Hope you can help me

Comment: `String.Format` does not prevent you from sql-injection. Use sql parameters instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I don't care about SQL-Injections at this Project, the Database is local.

Every user has its own.

Comment: @LucyKawaii Never trust _any_ user no matter your database is local or not.

Comment: uhmm.. yes, you are right^^ I'm a beginner, especially with SQL. Its the first i ever did with SQL. There is much i have to learn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't fix the exception - stop constructing SQL like this to start with. (The exception is due to a typo as Pheonyx suggested, but *don't* just fix that.)

Instead, use parameterized SQL, and specify the values as parameter values. Otherwise:

- You're leaving yourself open to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- Your code is harder to read
- You can easily end up with conversion issues, particularly with dates

See the documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) for more details - we can't tell what database you're targeting to give you more specific help, but typically you'll find a properties called `Parameters` on the relevant command class.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a typo

```
'{1]'
```

should be

```
'{1}'
```

(Note the different bracket)

Comment: Just found it myself ._. Searched 15 minutes for this

Answer (score 2):

Must be

```
 VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')
```